# Making struct with element from another struct (error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'type')

Tags: c, pointers

```
typedef struct testone
{
    int x;
    int y;
}t1;


 typedef struct testtwo
 {
    t1 *t;
    t->x curr_x


 }t2;
```

I am getting the below error, anyone know what the problem is?

> error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 't'

Thanks

Comment: The line `t->x curr_x` doesn't make sense in C. What are you trying to do here ?

Comment: I am trying to get the value of (t->x) and assign it to curr_x

Answer (score 2):

t->x isn't a defined type. all variables in structs, and in general, must be a type either defined by c or defined by you. I think what you are trying to do is have

```
typedef struct testtwo
{
    t1 *t;
    int curr_x;
}t2;
```

and then when you intialize a t2 struct you can assign the t1->x value to t2.curr_x

Comment: This seems to make sense. I'll try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `x->y` , You should initialize address of `y` in `x` , It's normal to get error. So You can use old style such as `x.y`